# How to set image background to UITabBarController iOS 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, background, ios5

Hello can someone help me with this pice of code. I have app with custom tab bar image an now in iOS5 the image is gone. I know that they have made changes on tab bar implementation and i'm not sure how to fix this.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 148);
UIView *viewa = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
UIImage *tabBarBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fasha-down.png"];
UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:tabBarBackgroundImage];


[viewa setBackgroundColor:color];
[[tabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:viewa atIndex:0];
[color release];
[viewa release];
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view]; 
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code to detect iOS version

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 5)  {
    [[tabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:viewa atIndex:0];
}else{
    [[tabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:viewa atIndex:1];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change source as below, you can fix this problem.

Old source:

```
[[tabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:viewa atIndex:0];
```

New source:

```
//1.Check version of iOS
if(iOSVersion <= 4.3){
    [[tabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:viewa atIndex:0];
}else{
//iOS5
    [[tabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:viewa atIndex:1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You save me a lots of headaches

Comment: iOSVersion is not Framework of variable. you need to create source code for checking iOS verion. Reference link: Check iPhone iOS Version

Answer (score 0):

```
// Change the tab bar background
UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
```