# tabbar background color in xcode 4.2 and ios 5

Tags: iphone

I have made an iPhone application in Xcode 4.2 and snow leopard in which I have set the navigation bar and tab bar background color by implementing following code

```
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 48);
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f/255.0f green:140.0f/255.0f    
    blue:131.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    [[self.tabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:v atIndex:0];
[v release];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f/255.0f    
    green:125.0f/255.0f blue:131.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

it is working fine but now if I am running this app in ios 5 and xcode 4.2 , navigation bar color set but tabbar background color doesn't set

How can I set background color of tabbar in ios 5? If someone know please help me.

Thanks alot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779736/how-to-set-image-background-to-uitabbarcontroller-ios-5

Answer (score 2):

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 48);//Setting a Frame.

    myTabView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];//Making Tab View

    // not supported on iOS4    
    UITabBar *tabBarr = [self.tabBar tabBar];
    if ([tabBarr respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:)])
    {
        // set it just for this instance
        [tabBarr setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hot-1.png"]];


        // set for all
        // [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage: ...
    }
    else
    {
        // ios 4 code here
        //[tabBarr setBackgroundColor:c];
    }

    //[myTabView  setBackgroundColor:c];//Setting Color Of TaBar.

    [myTabView  setAlpha:0.8];//Setting Alpha of TabView.

    [[self.tabBar tabBar] insertSubview:myTabView  atIndex:0];//Inserting Tab As SubView.
```

Use this instead of setting color to background of tabbar ....