# Make UItabbar transparent

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

So I have two tabbar items  in my tabbar and each of them has an image with a round corner, the rounded corner is at location where they meet, as you can see in the picture. I am trying to set the background image of the tabbar to be transparent instead of that black as you can see, but so far I keep bumping into some view that doesn't want to be transparent. Here is what I am using for the moment:

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITabBar class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent"]]];
```

I have also tried the next piece of code, but with no success.

```
[tabBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent"]]];
for(UIView *v in tabBar.subviews)
{
    if(v.class == NSClassFromString(@"_UITabBarBackgroundView")||v.class == NSClassFromString(@"UITabBarButton"))
    {
        [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent"]]];
    }
    for(UIView *vc in v.subviews)
    {
        [vc setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent"]]];
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? How can I find that view and make it transparent?

[image: tabbar too]
[image: tabbar]

Comment: try setting its alpha to 0

Comment: TRY : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7865588/1106035

Comment: if ios version >= 5.0 then try [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent.png"]];

Comment: Also i think your image name might be transparent.png/jpg not simply transparent

Comment: It has nothing to do with transparent.png, it detects automatically the .png

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a category for this, extending `UITabBarController` like:

**UITabBarController+TransparentBackground.h**

```
@interface UITabBarController (TransparentBackground) 
- (void) setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image;
@end
```

**UITabBarController+TransparentBackground.m**

```
#import "UITabBarController+TransparentBackground.h"
@implementation UITabBarController (TransparentBackground)

- (void) setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image 
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
    [self.view setOpaque:NO];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}

@end
```

Add `#import "UITabBarController+TransparentBackground.h"` in your `AppDelegate.m` file.

In Your `AppDelegate.m`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, Add the following two lines (at top):

```
[tabBarController setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomTabBarBackground.png"]];
[tabBarController.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Hope you get it working, by doing as said.

For more info on this: [REFRENCE](https://gist.github.com/darkseed/1157542)

### EDIT

Add Property to your `AppDelegate.h` by writing:

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;

Also do `@sythesize tabBarController;` in `AppDelegate.m` file.

And Connect this `IBOutlet property` with your corresponding `TabBarController` in `XIB`

Comment: If I paste that into the AppDelegate.m file, I get errors like :  Unknown receiver 'tabBarController'; did you mean 'UITabBarController'?

Comment: I am not using a XIB, I have a storyboard. I don't think that I can connect the IBOutlet to the storyboard.

Comment: Well, I cannot connect the IBOutlet to the tab bar controller from the storyboard, it doesn't want to go that way. I tried that by drag&drop to the storyboard from the AppDelegate and viceversa, and right click on stroryboard the tab bar controller, choosing referencing layout but still I cannot connect it.

Comment: `UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];`

`UIViewController* m1 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"m1"];`
`UIViewController* c1 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"c1"];`
`[self.tabBarController setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent"]];
    [self.tabBarController.view setNeedsDisplay];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[m1,c1];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` 
Am I missing something? Sorry about the format of this comment.